# How to pass service to own bundle configuration

Tags: symfony

I'm developing a bundle and want to set up existed cache service (implements `Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider`) to my service. The existed service name will be set up in configuration of bundle:

```
services:
    cache:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\FilesystemCache
        arguments: ["%kernel.cache_dir%/cache"]

my_bundle:
    cache_provider: cache
```

When I try get this service with `$container->get($config['cache_provider']);`  in `MyBundleExtension`, I have this error:

```
The service definition "cache" does not exist.
```

and calling of `$container->has($config['cache_provider']);` returns `false`.

I injects `@service_container` to my service and gets cache in it - it works. But injecting of container is not good practice.

Do you have any ideas about it?

Comment: Have a look at Compiler Passes: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html

Comment: thanks, in the second compiler pass I successfully get needed service.

Comment: but I has second error - container cannot save object to parameter:

$obj = new Service();
$container->setParameter('param', $obj);

will throw an exception:

RuntimeException in XmlDumper.php line 343:
Unable to dump a service container if a parameter is an object or a resource.

Comment: @BenjaminPaap it seems that pass service to another service is imposiible with container parameters.

Comment: Could you please tell me what are you intend to do with your 'cache_provider' then I'll suggest you some solutions. Because when Extension being compiled, the service container hasn't been built yet, thus you cannot get your service there.

Comment: @Tuannguyen I want to use it :) My service will fetch some data from db, and I want to use globally registered cache provider.
The trouble is that `$container->setParameter('mybundle.object', new Class())` does not work - the error message are above.

Comment: Maybe you could use an aliasing service http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html#aliasing